# A little Problem in Trigonometry (Multiple Angle)

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan^2 \theta = 1 + 2\tan^2 \phi$, show that $\cos 2\phi = 1 + 2\cos2\theta$.

What I have done..

$$\implies \tan^2 \theta = 1 + 2\tan^2 \phi\\
\implies 1 + \tan^2 \theta = 2 + 2\tan^2 \phi\\
\implies 1 + \tan^2 \theta = 2(1 + \tan^2 \phi)\\
\implies \sec^2 \theta = 2(\sec^2 \phi)$$

Comment: On the left for example if you want tan squared theta, put it between dollar signs. "dollar" \tan ^2 \theta "dollar" becomes $\tan^2 \theta$ by the interpreter here. Note how you need initial backslashes before tan and theta, to tell interpreter tan is a function and theta a variable. (Looks like Sanath already fixed...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your steps are fine you just need to do the following (I'm putting your steps first):
\begin{align*}
\tan^{2}\theta & = 1+2 \tan^{2}\phi\\
1+\tan^{2}\theta & = 2+2 \tan^{2}\phi\\
\sec^2 \theta & = 2 \sec^2 \phi\\
\text{Do the following to continue:}\\
\frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta} & =  \frac{2}{\cos^2 \phi}\\
\cos^2 \phi & = 2 \cos^2 \theta\\
\text{using the half angle formula}\\
\frac{1+\cos 2 \phi}{2} & = 1+\cos2 \theta\\
1+\cos 2 \phi & = 2(1+\cos2 \theta)\\
\cos 2\phi & = 1 +2\cos 2\theta.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think this is a homework question; so please do not post the full answer. Rather, give a hint.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I am feeling completely helpless on the part $\cos ^2 phi\ = 2 cos ^2 theta\ .

Comment: recall $\cos \theta = 1/\sec \theta$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar even if that is true Swetank had done most of it and any hint that I give would be just reiterating what I posted.

Comment: @Anurag still not :( sec^2 theta to 2cos^2 theta?

Comment: @Swetank I have added one more step to my proof for clarity.

Comment: @Anurag yes yes! that cross-multiplication part i wasn't able to visualize. Thanks you!

Comment: @Anurag But at the end '2' is missing. It should be cos2phi = 1+2cos2theta. Would you please edit that.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Componendo & Dividendo on $$\frac{\tan^2\theta}1=\frac{1+2\tan^2\phi}1$$

$$\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\frac{1-(1+2\tan^2\phi)}{1+(1+2\tan^2\phi)}$$

$$\implies\cos2\theta=-\frac{\tan^2\phi}{1+\tan^2\phi}=-\sin^2\phi$$
$$\implies\cos2\theta=-\frac{1-\cos2\phi}2$$

Comment: @Swetank, How about this?